# How to calculate the $\limsup$ of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, limsup-and-liminf

I'm not at all familiar with how such computations work.

Let $m > 0$, and $\mathbf{1}_{A}: \mathbb{R} \to \{0, 1\}$ be defined by
$$\mathbf{1}_A(x) = \begin{cases}
1, & x \in A \\
0, & x \notin A\text{.}
\end{cases}$$

Let $(A_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be the sequence of sets $$A_n = \begin{cases}
\left[\dfrac{n-1}{m}, \dfrac{n}{m} \right], & n \leq m \\
\varnothing, & n > m\text{.}
\end{cases}$$

Consider the sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \{0, 1\}$ is defined by $$f_n = \mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{A}_n}\text{.}$$

> How do I calculate the value of  $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$$ almost everywhere (based on the Lebesgue measure) for $x \in [0, 1]$?

I have a ton of books on analysis, but none of them define the $\limsup$ of a sequence of functions (at least, as far as I can tell).

Digging around MSE, I seem to find two definitions of the $\limsup$ of sequence of functions. The first one is
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = \inf_{n \geq 1}\sup_{k \geq n}f_k(x) = \inf_{n \geq 1}\sup_{k \geq n}\mathbf{1}_{A_k}\text{.}$$
So if I consider $\sup_{k \geq n}\mathbf{1}_{A_k}$, I have
$$\sup_{k \geq n}\mathbf{1}_{A_k} = \sup\left\{\mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{n-1}{m}, \frac{n}{m} \right]}, \mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{n}{m}, \frac{n+1}{m} \right]}, \cdots \right\}$$
and I'm not sure how to handle this.

Another definition I've seen on MSE is
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{k \geq n}\mathbf{1}_{A_k}$$
and I run into the same problem here.

I haven't been provided a definition for $\limsup$ and was provided this problem. I suspect I don't know the definition because I didn't learn analysis via Baby Rudin (and I can't find it in there).

**Please do not use the "infinitely often" equivalence in $\limsup$; I am not allowed to use that for this purpose.**

Comment: It's just the pointwise $\limsup$, i.e. the function whose value at $x$ is the $\limsup$ of the sequence of real numbers $f_n(x)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler So let's consider $x \in [0, 1]$. We know that one of the $\mathbf{1}_{A_k}$ must be equal to $1$. In such a case, the $\sup$ would generate $1$ and thus the $\inf$ would be $1$. However, what I'm not getting is what would happen as $n \to \infty$. Would the $\limsup$ thus be $0$?

Comment: It's just the pointwise $\limsup$. Fix $x\in [0, 1]$ then for large $n$, $A_n = \emptyset$, hence $1_{A_n}(x) = 0$, which means that beyond some $N$, all $f_n(x) = 0$, hence the tail of the sequence of $\sup$ is $0$, hence $\limsup$ is $0$.

Comment: @stackex33 Thank you!